# IIS cant create a .net 3.5 app pool

Tags: .net, iis

I'm trying to host a .net 3.5 website on my server.

I installed the 3.5 role and restarted the server and restarted.

I still can't create an app pool with .net 3.5.

It's IIS7 server 2008.

Comment: Please edit your question with some more detail. Are you getting an error message? What exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 3.5 still runs on the 2.0 CLR. The framework versions 3.0 and 3.5 only added to the Base Class Library and added additional frameworks. 3.0 added WCF, WPF, and Workflow. It also contained a lot of the base framework additions for Linq which was added in 3.5.  These still run on the 2.0 CLR. Framework version 4.0 also came with an upgrade to the CLR.

Answer (score 5):

You can't select 3.5 as a version in IIS. Only 2.0 and 4.0. Not sure if 1.1 will work in IIS 7.
If you want to publish a 3.5 site, select 2.0 as the app pool .net runtime.

3.5 lies on top of 2.0.

**Update**
If you would like to install the .NET 4 runtime in IIS.
First just install the runtime and after that run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

This will register the v4 runtime in IIS.